# Angular Translate set variable in App.Config

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Angular App with `Angular Translate` installed on it.

This is my app.js file (only interested part):

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider, $ionicFilterBarConfigProvider, $httpProvider, $translateProvider) {

    $translateProvider.translations('it', {       
        SEARCH: 'Cerca',
    })

    $translateProvider.translations('en', {       
        SEARCH: 'Search',
    })

    //... Various .state(...

});

//Translate config
$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');

$ionicFilterBarConfigProvider.placeholder("Search");
```

What I need to do is to change the last line, the `"Search"` has to be taken from the translation, based on the translation selected.

I've tried this:

```
var SRC_WORD = $filter('translate')('SEARCH');
$ionicFilterBarConfigProvider.placeholder(SRC_WORD)
```

Not working.

I've tried also this, but of course is not inside the HTML so it won't work:

```
$ionicFilterBarConfigProvider.placeholder("{{'SEARCH' | translate }}")
```

No luck, where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Service providers (`$ionicFilterBarConfigProvider`) are only available in config phase, and service instances (`$ionicFilterBarConfig`) are only available in run phase.

The meaning of this separation is that config phase (`config` block) is used to configure service instances before they are instantiated.

In some cases it is possible to expose service provider as an instance to configure it dynamically in run phase:

```
app.config(function ($provide, $ionicFilterBarConfigProvider) {
  $provide.value('$ionicFilterBarConfigProvider', $ionicFilterBarConfigProvider);
});

app.controller(..., function ($filter, $ionicFilterBarConfigProvider) {
  var SRC_WORD = $filter('translate')('SEARCH');
  $ionicFilterBarConfigProvider.placeholder(SRC_WORD)
});
```

This method comes without warranty and totally depends on what happens inside particular service.